# Watch out for duplicates (public service announcement)

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Hopefully, soon, we will go public - as such we will more than likely get many enthusiastic new members, which will be awesome!

One thing we need to do is keep an eye out for duplicates of what is already is here.  But, not necessarily downvote the poster of the duplicate as I have seen on other sites.

What sayeth you?

Comment: I agree we should not downvote the poster, but perhaps it is worth making explicit for users new to the SE-business what should be done, namely: vote to *close* as duplicate or *flag* as duplicate (if not in possession of the former privelege), using the links below the post.

Comment: @quid absolutely, educating new users would be the better path.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly agree with you that we shouldn't downvote duplicates, so long as they would not be downvoted if they *weren't* duplicates. It's going to be tough for new users to figure out if their question(s) is/are already covered by other posts on the site. We can simply point them in the direction of the original question. If we downvote their question, we're going to discourage them.

Comment: Also when users do not know a popular known title about the question they are asking, which is a duplicate then their questions are downvoted and this shouldn't happen.